# sublime text indent style

Tags: sublimetext, auto-indent

I'm using sublime text 3, it has auto indent. It works pretty good, but it uses style different than I preffer. Sublime uses something like that

```
do
{
  /* code */
} while (/* condition */);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  /* code */
  return 0;
}
```

while I'd prefer something like that

```
do {
  /* code */
} while (/* condition */);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  /* code */
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to change sublime's indent style?

Comment: Problem solved, just found files with indent rules

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and accept it, incase anyone else comes by looking for the same answer. Glad to see you were able to answer your own question so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can after tab press ctrl+j.

I trying modify about indent the configure files, but useless.

If anyone know how to modify, please tell me :D

Answer (score 0):

Change the snippets in the "**C++.sublime-package**" in the **Packages** folder.
 
In **Linux**:

```
/opt/sublime_text/Packages
```

In **Windows**:

```
C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages
```

Or in Sublime **Preferences** > **Browse Packages...** Then edit the language you want.

PS: C and C++ are in the same folder "**C++**"